# How to generate .proto files from Protocol Buffers .NET code?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

So having our classes with attributes in folder how to generate .proto markup files out from them (to get for example C++ code)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By "classes with attributes", do you mean attributes suitable for protobuf-net? If so, protobuf-net has a `GetProto` method which will provide the schema based on a root type:

```
string proto = Serializer.GetProto<SomeType>();
```

Despite the rumors to the contrary, this method in v2 has been re-implemented for quite some time now.

Comment: As a matter of fact,  you can use this now.. myProto = myModel.GetSchema(typeof(SomeType), ProtoSyntax.Proto3);